# Ld gives me segmentation fault when linking three objects

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/Docs/title.htm) and at some point I'm supposed to link multiple objects with `ld` but when I try to link them with this command:

```
ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o scrn.o -melf_i386
```

...I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

And when I use:

```
ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o -melf_i386
```

...`ld` successfully links the objects.

This is what I'm using to compile the files:

```
nasm -f elf -o start.o start.asm
gcc -m32 -Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fno-pie -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -nostdinc -fno-builtin -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -m32 -Wall -O -fstrength-reduce -fno-pie -fomit-frame-pointer -finline-functions -nostdinc -fno-builtin -c -o scrn.o scrn.c
```

As for the files, here are the links for [main.c](https://pastebin.com/kirNaw8u), [start.asm](https://pastebin.com/VXCZDRbb), [link.ld](https://pastebin.com/GCDQkhYD) and [system.h](https://pastebin.com/sFTvSyMZ). The `scrn.c` file is completely empty.

Comment: Could you post crashed ld backtrace?

Comment: As a workaround try to remove all object files `*.o` and rebuild everything from scratch.